# How can I enable Server GC in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, .net-core

I have a .NET Core app (*MyApp.exe*) developed in **VS2017** running on the **1.0.4** version of the *SDK*. I have tried adding an `App.config` with the following entries:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <gcServer enabled="true"/>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Which on build is renamed to: `MyApp.config`.

But this does not change the *GC* mode; Any ideas?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Based on [this source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj), you do that via the csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <ServerGarbageCollection>true</ServerGarbageCollection>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: is this still true for .Net Core 2

Comment: Something that might be useful to people to know:  Based on what I found [here](http://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/getting-organised-with-microsoft-orleans-2-0-in-net-core/) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/issues/4418), I discovered that despite doing `dotnet build` again, the settings weren't changing.  Turns out doing a `dotnet clean` first should do the trick.

Comment: Yes a rebuild maybe required.

Comment: This is still true for even .NET Core 3.1

Answer (score 4):

There are few ways and they vary depends on the dotnet version.

[image]

`runtimeconfig.json file:`

```json
{
   "runtimeOptions": {
      "configProperties": {
         "System.GC.Server": true
      }
   }
}
```

`Project file:`

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <ServerGarbageCollection>true</ServerGarbageCollection>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

More details you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-config/garbage-collector#flavors-of-garbage-collection)